# Find the center of a shape (path) on a canvas (Android Studio)

Tags: android, canvas, shapes

Is it possible to find the center of a shape on a canvas in Android studio? I've logged the touch points and can't seem to figure it out. It does however appear that the canvas (0,0) point is the top left, but the paths/shapes on the canvas see the center point as (0,0).

For an example of what I'm talking about check out the attached image, I'm trying to find where the green dot is.

Thanks in advance for any help.

[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmeV2.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the center of a `Path` use the method [computeBounds(bounds,exact)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#computeBounds(android.graphics.RectF,%20boolean)) which will set the first argument `RectF bounds` to the extent of the Path. Then it is just a matter of getting the mean of the left right and top bottom coordinates to get the geometric center of the path.

```
// mPath is your path. Must contain more than 1 path point
RectF bounds = new RectF();
mPath.computeBounds(bounds, false); // fills rect with bounds
PointF center = new PointF((bounds.left + bounds.right) / 2,
                           (bounds.top + bounds.bottom) / 2);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :-D

Comment: Just mentioning that for highly non-regular shapes you might calculate the centroid (simple center mass) == the mean of all x-points and the mean of all y-points. But the poster's question doesn't appear to need this refinement. :-)

Comment: @markE The path object does not allow access to the points so the point mass center would have to be computed as points are added. But using the points will not give a good center of mass. Eg You have 2 points (0,0) & ( 0,10) then 100 points within 2 units of (1000,5) the point mass center would be at the far right and the visual (or area) mass center a little left of (500,5) Apart from a whole pile of complicated math you can use a canvas to render the path(low res) and then get the mean of non transparent pixel coordinates for a good center of visual mass.

Comment: The computeBounds worked for me even with customized shapes.

Answer (score 0):

> No Need for Mathematical Calculations

```
RectF bounds = new RectF();
mPath.computeBounds(bounds, false);
float centerX = rectF.centerX();
float centerY = rectF.centerY();
```